# Proving nice divisibility

Tags: proof-writing

Let $n=10x+y$ where $n$, $x$ and $y$ are positive integers.
Prove that $n$ is divisible by $13$ iff $x+4y$ is divisible by $13$.

I let $n=13k$, thereafter mutliplied $x+4y$ by $10$, to get $10x+40y$ and $n=10x+y$. Subtract the two to get $39y$ which is clearly divisible by $13$, but I don't know how to structure this proof.

Comment: @peterwhy I realised how much of a no-brainer it was after working out.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $10x+y=13M$ and $y=13M-10x$. Then:
$$x+4y=x+4(13M-10x)
=52M-39x=13P.$$
Assume $x+4y=13N
x=13N-4y$
Then:
$$10x+y=10(13N-4y)+y
=130N-39y=13Q.$$

Comment: Please use Mathjax to format your answer. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: no thanks @sudeep5221 immanswering my own qn.

Answer (score 0):

$n=10x+y. 13|n \iff 13|(x+4y)?$

$(40x+4y)-(x+4y)=39x$

$(x+4y)+39x=4(10x+y)$

If a prime divides two numbers, it divides their sum and their difference.

IF $13|(x+4y)$ and $13|39x$, so $13|4(10x+y)$.  Since $13\not|4 \implies  13|10x+y$

By similar reasoning, one can prove the other direction .